# using file_get_contents to authenticate and access an htaccess protected file

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I need to reach a foreign .php page protected by a regular .htaccess file (Auth type Basic, htpasswords etc...).

I'd like to send the user and password needed through the request. Is it possible? I would like to avoid `cURL` and all `pecl_http` dependent functions if possible...

Comment: Thank you @jack, I couldn't find that one in the search results. Let's hope that from now on the keywords cumulate and our fellow developers will find their way to this answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Off-hand, I believe you can use a context to do that:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array (
    'http' => array (
        'header' => 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: According to comment by `chris dot vigelius at gmx dot net` in PHP documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) the `header` parameter MUST be an array (bug = https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41051).