# How can PHP detect whether remote server is requesting authentication

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script that will loop through a set of URLs. Each URL points directly to a jpeg file. The images are not on the same server. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363925/check-whether-image-exists-on-remote-url) but I can't use the CURL libraries (not active on my server) and when I use @getimagesize I found that my function returned false for all images; however, I worked out that the cause as follows: if I type the valid URL into a web browser, I am prompted to authenticate against the remote server. If I type an invalid URL against the remote server, then I receive 404 instead.

So my question becomes - given a remote URL, can PHP detect whether the remote server is prompting for login? If so, that would surely be faster than parsing the results of the valid and authenticated URL calls. If not, then how can I have the PHP script authenticate itself in order to check the remote image?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002980/using-file-get-contents-to-authenticate-and-access-an-htaccess-protected-file for how to send the authentication headers with `file_get_contents`. But I don't think there's a way to find out that this is the reason for the failure.

Comment: Thanks. I ran with the answer that explained to query $http_response_header and linked to the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A HTTP call with `file_get_contents()` will automatically create the variable `$http_response_header` which is an array containing the HTTP response headers. From there you can detect if there was an error.

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) for details.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the type of authentication, if you use  get_headers() on the remote url it will return "WWW-Authenticate" and it should be returning a "401 Unauthorized".

really you should moev to a server with curl, as it can then send the correct credentials

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I haven't tested yet but accepted the other answer already. We're shutting down this server soon - just a last minute task before it goes.